# Separate routes if subdomain is present in rails

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to separate routes in rails 3.1 when a subdomain is present? I want to use one collection of routes when subdomains is used and one if not.

e.g

```
if request.subdomain.present?
  root ....
  resources ...
else
  root ....
  resources ...
end
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SubdomainRoute

  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end

end
```

---

```
class NoSubdomainRoute

  def self.matches?(request)
    !request.subdomain.present?
  end

end
```

---

```
  constraints(NoSubdomainRoute) do
    resources :profile # matches if there is not a subdomain
  end

  constraints(SubdomainRoute) do
    resources :profile # matches if there is a subdomain
  end
```

Comment: And if there isn't a subdomain present I want to use a different collection. Should I wrap all routes in 2 constraints then or what?